# PR2 motion plan whole body

Tags: ros, ompl, pr2, ompl-ros-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use OMPL for planning the whole body not just the arms?
I mean including the base.
If so, could somebody point me to such example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48530/pr2-motion-plan-whole-body/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/48028/could-ompl-deal-with-mobile-manipulation/) may give you a guide conceptually.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0